# Airodump-ng library interface

Tags: interface, aircrack-ng

I need a library interface for airodump-ng? C++/C or Python or anything will do. I only need to find the ap and station around my area along with it's rate and signal. Data are not needed. If Airodump-ng doesn't provide any programming interface, is there a library similar to what it does? Or if there's not even a library like that? Anyone has a clue on how airodump-ng work? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any API for airodump-ng.

You can read the source code at [airodump-ng.c](http://trac.aircrack-ng.org/browser/trunk/src/airodump-ng.c) and link directly to it and calls its functions.

You could also look at [wifite](http://code.google.com/p/wifite/) which is a script which automates the airocrack-ng functionality, source code [here](https://github.com/derv82/wifite/blob/master/wifite.py).